# What is the correct way to update UI asynchronously?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

So I have this code:

```
int i = 3;
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        for (;;)
        {
            t1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:i target:self selector:@selector(updateUI) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        }
    });
});
```

And so what i'm doing is i'm updating the UI every 3 seconds in a game, but I want to be able to change the interval on which the timer goes off so I used an infinite for loop with the timer in it. My problem is that when I use the main queue it doesn't do it async but I need to use the main queue for updating the UI so I don't know what to do.

Comment: Change `repeats` to `YES`?

Comment: Well then you can't change the interval the timer goes off on.

Comment: Sure, but you're not changing it anyway.

Comment: Well I will later in the code.

Comment: Create the next timer with whatever interval you need when the last one fires.

Comment: If by "UI" you mean UIKit you cannot safely update it from secondary threads. you may want to consider a more traditional design for a game loop. Have you considered the new SpriteKit in iOS 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create NSTimer in main thread, then selector call in main thread.

```
- (void)updateTimer
{
    // destroy timer
    [t1 invalidate];
    // start new timer
    t1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:i target:self selector:@selector(updateUI) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}


- (void)updateUI
{
    ......
    [self updateTimer];
}
```

Need call `[self updateTimer]` in start application, to begin the update UI.